# ipatool failed with an exception in xcode 9

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa

I'm trying to export the ipa file for Ad-hoc Distribution. Here I'm getting the following issue

**ipatool failed with an exception**
[image]

I tried many times it getting same error only. Finally, I just clicked fast next before below red error comes. I get the ipa file, but this ipa is not working.

I installed this ipa from Xcode it showing

> **App installation failed An unknown error has occurred**

I checked with my distribution certificate & Provisioning Profile too. I created new Provisioning profile but it not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For whole day I too struck by this issue I did many solutions but not working..... I did very small mistake one of the solution is

restart the Xcode & try. I tried this by wrongly that is close all projects finally close the Xcode (it works ), but I quit Xcode shortly

Final solution is close Xcode clearly (by closing every projects) and archive it...

I thing it’s helps you

Answer (score 2):

Got same error, uncheck option `Rebuild from Bitcode` resolves the problem. 
Able to generate archive successfully

Make sure you have stripped simulator architecture's( x86_64, i386) while generating archive. You can add script to remove unwanted architecture's in Post Action section under Archive tab in Edit schema.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this could happen due to the problem in the External library or framework used in your project.

To trace which framework is causing the issue, you could remove the framework from the project. Comment those lines which use that framework and start Archiving the iOS build. If that works, you could replace that faulty framework with the latest stable release.

Comment: yes i'm using Charts framework but before working fine now it causing these error

Comment: ok. Is it something updated the cocoa pods to latest release? Its working fine earlier means with the same Charts framework version.

Comment: there is no change in frameworks using the same only & I'm not using the cocoa pods in this project

Answer (score 0):

I too struck by this issue!

I solved this problems after removing 'Asset/Unity Technologies/Recorder' in my unity project.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be the one making the framework like i did and your framework causing those ipatool failed issue. you can check on these:

1. Remove all dependency in your project and try adding it one by one, make sure which framework causing the build error, check for newest stable version or report to the framework owner to fix the issue.
2. Disable everything related to code coverage in your Project Scheme Test Section before building your framework for others to use.

[code coverage disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l53XT.png)

3. In my case the framework was built without error, but it will generate ipatool error on .ipa archive on Project that using my framework. Been trying to solve this issue and found out that there's a line of code which causing the ipatool failed:

```
    if (@available(iOS 10.0, *)) {

    }
```

changed to this code solve the issue for me:

```
    if(([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 10.0)) {

    }
```

Note: I'm using Xcode 11.3.1 with debug SDK 13.2 and build target iOS 9.0 with Bitcode Enabled

Answer (score -1):

If unchecking option of `Rebuild from Bitcode` is not an available option. Then updating Xcode to the latest version might help. Reason being the third party framework that you are using might be build with Xcode version greater than your Xcode version.